# How to get the location in the headers of a request in a .Net API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I am working on a log of logins for security issues in user accounts, so I want to record the location and device from which users log in, this to alert of possible suspicious logins with their accounts themselves.

But I don't know if this data is stored by default in the header of the query or if it is better to assign that data in the header before making the request to be able to read it in my API according to the name that I assign to it.

But I don't know if this is the correct way to solve this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "location" and "device"? The IP address of the client? The User Agent string?

Comment: You probably want to look up a service like https://www.geolocation.com/

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes to the IP from where the request was made and the location.
My ultimate goal is to make it as similar as possible to how google does when you log in from a new device.

Comment: I will carry out a couple of tests with your recommendation I hope to be successful, thanks for your help @RoadieRich

Comment: Yes, it is one of the data that I need
Thanks for your help @gunr2171